# Get brightness value for a picture

Tags: software-recommendation, webcam, image-processing

I use openHAB and want to use an old mobile phone as an day/night indicator. I have installed a webcam app and it is filming the sky. I can get the latest shot via `http://[ip]/shot.jpg`.

Can I get a "brightness value" like this: `curl http://[ip]/shot.jpg | some-command --get-brightness`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question is answered [here on Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/35973/24413) by [Steve Barnes](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/142/steve-barnes).

> Two possibilities:
>
> Use imagemagick to check the brightness of the image will work as long as the phone camera does not have auto-exposure or it is turned off, otherwise it will only work for extreme values, (dark/light), e.g.
>
> ```
>  convert <image> -colorspace Gray -format "%[fx:quantumrange*image.mean]" info:
> ```
>
> exiftool can parse the EXIF information from the file and extract the "Light Value" which should give you a reasonably consistent reading, (assuming that the camera on your specific phone includes this tag).
>
> Both tools are free, gratis & open source and available for most platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to exiftool, you can use [exiv2](https://github.com/Exiv2/exiv2), which I found to be much faster than exiftool and imagemagick.

### Comparison (on Raspberry Pi Zero)

Tested with always the same 4056 x 3040 image

### Imagemagick convert

```
pi@rpicamhq:/mnt/ramdisk $ time convert image.jpg -colorspace Gray -format "%[fx:quantumrange*image.mean]" info:
1039.34
real    0m1,989s
user    0m1,753s
sys     0m0,193s
```

### Imagemagick identify format

```
pi@rpicamhq:/mnt/ramdisk $ time identify -format "%[mean]\n" image.jpg
1128.99

real    0m3,357s
user    0m3,133s
sys     0m0,199s

pi@rpicamhq:/mnt/ramdisk $ time identify -format "%[fx:mean]\n" image.jpg
0.0172272

real    0m3,435s
user    0m3,274s
sys     0m0,130s

pi@rpicamhq:/mnt/ramdisk $ time identify -format "%[fx:quantumrange*mean]\n" image.jpg
1128.99

real    0m3,387s
user    0m3,218s
sys     0m0,139s
```

### Imagemagick identify exif

```
pi@rpicamhq:/mnt/ramdisk $ time identify -format '%[EXIF:BrightnessValue]'

real    0m0,275s
user    0m0,071s
sys     0m0,040s
```

### exiftool

```
pi@rpicamhq:/mnt/ramdisk $ time exiftool -a -u -g1 image.jpg | grep 'Brightness'
Brightness Value                : 0.01

real    0m2,647s
user    0m2,429s
sys     0m0,191s
```

### exiv2

```
pi@rpicamhq:/mnt/ramdisk $ time exiv2 -PElt image.jpg | grep 'Brightness'
Brightness                      0.01

real    0m0,097s
user    0m0,042s
sys     0m0,050s
```

### exiv2, w/o grep

```
pi@rpicamhq:/mnt/ramdisk $ time exiv2 -PElt -g Brightness image.jpg
Brightness                      0.01

real    0m0,070s
user    0m0,024s
sys     0m0,039s
```